# Need to get repaint() to stop overwriting my previous graphics

Tags: java, graphics

My paint code won't stop overwriting the previous graphics I draw. Whenever I drag my mouse, it's supposed to create a dot and leave it there as it draws a new one in a new location. That doesn't seem to be happening here because when paint() is called, it clears the previous dots. I'll be posting the full code first then the paint() section and then the Mouse Dragged listener. I'm using NetBeans IDE with its prebuilt JForm

1) Full Code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author User-Pc
 */

import DrawCanvas.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Paint extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Paint
     */

    public Color penColor = Color.BLACK, bgColor = Color.WHITE;
    public boolean touchState = false, penState = false, eraseState = false;
    public int penSize = 5;
    public Point mousePoint = new Point();
    public Map map;

    public class DrawCanvas extends JPanel{
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            penSize = jSlider1.getValue();
            penState = jToggleButton1.isSelected();
            eraseState = jToggleButton2.isSelected();
            setBackground(bgColor);
            g.setColor(penColor);
            this.paintComponent(g);
            if(touchState){
                g.fillOval(mousePoint.x, mousePoint.y, penSize, penSize);
            }
        }
        public void DrawCanvas()
        {
            addMouseMotionListener(
                new MouseMotionAdapter()
                    {
                        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt)
                        {
                            mousePoint = evt.getPoint();
                            System.out.println(mousePoint);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    } 

    DrawCanvas canvas = new DrawCanvas();

    public Paint() {
        initComponents();
        jPanel2.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        canvas.setBounds(canvas.getX() + 1, canvas.getY() + 1, 0, 0);
        canvas.setSize(jPanel2.getSize().width - 2, jPanel2.getSize().height - 2);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton2 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Paint [Reyes, Duazo, Bermudo]"));

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));
        jPanel2.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel2MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 396, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Drawing Tools"));

        jLabel1.setText("Shapes");

        jButton3.setText("Circle");

        jButton4.setText("Rectangle");

        jLabel2.setText("Custom Parameters");

        jLabel3.setText("Pen Thickness");

        jSlider1.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        jSlider1.setMaximum(50);
        jSlider1.setMinimum(5);
        jSlider1.setValue(5);
        jSlider1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jSlider1StateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Pen Color");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setText("Background Color");

        buttonGroup1.add(jToggleButton1);
        jToggleButton1.setText("Pen");

        buttonGroup1.add(jToggleButton2);
        jToggleButton2.setText("Eraser");

        jLabel4.setText("5");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 220, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 220, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4))
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton5)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton6)
                .addContainerGap(163, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 466, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(Paint.this, "Choose a pen color", penColor);
        if(color != null)
            penColor = color;

    }                                        

    private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
        jLabel4.setText(Integer.toString(jSlider1.getValue()));
    }                                     

    private void jPanel2MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        touchState = true;
        mousePoint = evt.getPoint();
        System.out.println(mousePoint);
        repaint();
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Paint.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Paint.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Paint.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Paint.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Paint().setVisible(true);
        });

    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

2) Relevant to painting:

```
@Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            penSize = jSlider1.getValue();
            penState = jToggleButton1.isSelected();
            eraseState = jToggleButton2.isSelected();
            setBackground(bgColor);
            g.setColor(penColor);
            this.paintComponent(g);
            if(touchState){
                g.fillOval(mousePoint.x, mousePoint.y, penSize, penSize);
            }
        }
```

3) Mouse Dragged Event

```
private void jPanel2MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {     

        touchState = true;
        mousePoint = evt.getPoint();
        System.out.println(mousePoint);
        repaint();
    }
```

I would prefer to not have to use a data structure to store the value of every point and then repaint.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the super's painting method within your paint method override, and this prevents component housekeeping painting from being done, including removal of "dirty" pixels. Suggestions:

- Override a JPanel's `paintComponent` method, not its `paint` method
- Call the related super's painting method as the first line of your override. So if you're overriding `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, call `super.paintComponent(g)` on the first line.
- If you need to draw multiple dots, then either draw them to a BufferedImage or create an `ArrayList<Point>` and place your points into the array list and iterate through them.